# XSLT 2.0 disjunction in test expression

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I would like to know if there is a way to format dusjunctions in test expressions in a more convinient way. Currently it looks like something like this:

```
<xsl:when test="local-name() = 'p' or local-name() = 'ul' or local-name() = 'sec'" >
    <xsl:call-template name="whatever" />
</xsl:when>
```

If I have about 10 elements I want to test here it is very inconvinient to find which ones I have already added.

Is there something similar to this in 2.0?

```
<xsl:when test="local-name() = 'p'|'ul'|'sec'" >
```

**UPDATE:**

How about this in 2.0:

```
<xsl:when test="local-name() = ('p','ui','sec')" >
   <xsl:call-template name="whatever" />
</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Your update appears to incorporate the disjunction I described in my answer, but it isn't namespace safe.  Tomalak's suggestion of using the `self::` axis is the right way.  I remind my students that `name()` and `local-name()` are to be used *only* for exposition and should *never* be used for testing.  You (and many others) are abusing `local-name()` by using it for testing.  The reason they exist are only to reveal information about a node.  It is not namespace-safe (and namespaces are very important in XML), and it doesn't take advantage of the XDM data model.

Comment: Okay so is there a way to make the self axis a bit more convinient instead of typing a disjunction for every rule?

Comment: Looks like <xsl:when test="self::p|ui|sec" > works fine thanks.

Comment: @Peter Beware that `self::p|ui|sec` !== `self::p|self::ui|self::sec` !

Comment: Very true I just learned this on behalf of an other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Tomalak not to work with `local-name()` and that the typical approach is to match using the `self::` axis:

```
<xsl:when test="self::n:p or self::n:ul or self::n:para">
    <xsl:call-template name="whatever" />
</xsl:when>
```

To answer your specific question regarding disjunction, yes, XSLT 2.0 will give you exactly what you need, and in a namespace-safe manner, but I tell my XSLT students it really isn't any more elegant than the above built-in syntax.

XSLT 2.0 allows the test `singleton = ( sequence )` and returns `true()` if the singleton is equal to any member of the sequence.  So, the following will return `true()`:

```
'b' = ( 'a', 'b', 'c' )
```

If you were working with HTML in no namespace, you could use the following test of a singleton against a sequence:

```
test="node-name(.)=( QName('','p'), QName('','ul'), QName('','sec') )
```

In XHTML  you could use the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="ns" select="'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'"/>
<xsl:if test="node-name(.)=( QName($ns,'p'), QName($ns,'ul'), QName($ns,'sec') )"/>
```

But, really, I don't think that is any better than:

```
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
...
test="self::x:p or self::x:ul or self::x:para"
```

I suppose if you were working *only* with XHTML you could use the following:

```
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
...
test="self::p or self::ul or self::para"
```

But in my professional work I've only every used xpath-default-namespace when I'm guaranteed my input is only in a single namespace.  I never use it if my input can have multiple namespaces.

Answer (score 4):

Don't work with `local-name()` at all, use proper namespace declarations and node tests.

This assumes that there is an `xmlns:n="..."` declaration in your XSLT.

```
<xsl:when test="self::n:p or self::n:ul or self::n:para">
    <xsl:call-template name="whatever" />
</xsl:when>
```

Even nicer, use template matching.

```
<xsl:template match="n:p | n:ul | n:para">
    <xsl:call-template name="whatever" />
</xsl:template>
```

---

If you absolutely *must* use string expressions and `local-name()`, you could work with `index-of()`

```
<xsl:when test="index-of(('p', 'ul', 'sec'), local-name())">
    <xsl:call-template name="whatever" />
</xsl:when>
```

<sup>** This works because `index-of()` returns a non-zero number when it finds a match, and non-zero numbers evaluate to `true` in Boolean context.*</sup>

though I strongly recommend against doing that in this particular case because it contradicts the design principles of XSLT.

Comment: Your answer did help me to see a bit more clearly I'll admit it, but I was more interested in a simple string disjunction solution like the one I have added.

Comment: I see. Well, instead of an update to your question, post it as an answer of your own. It's more idiomatic than `index-of`, I'll up-vote it and you can even accept your own answer, if you like.

Comment: My evaluation is that your solution is not namespace safe, uses the functional library for inappropriate purposes and is not harmonious with the XDM data model.

Comment: @G.KenHolman If the OP wants a namespace-safe solution, he can use one of the two other proposals I've made. The whole point of using `local-name()` is to have a non-namespace-aware name check. Apart from that, yes, `index-of()` is not the ideal candidate for the purpose (you posted that solution - should I have copied it silently?), but it works correctly. What's your point?

Comment: I suppose my point was the OP was asking for disjunctive comparison which I interpret as `singleton  comparison  sequence` or `sequence comparison sequence`.  Please forgive me if I left the impression I was criticizing the use of `index-of()`.  As for non-namespace-aware checks, one could use `self::*:p` for that without using the exposition functions.  And `self::*:p` is expressing exactly the semantic of "I don't care what the namespace is".  I acknowledge it sounds pedantic, but in the classroom it is important to base instruction on sound principles.

Comment: @Tomalak In the thread above I see that the OP has deleted a comment after yours to which I was referring when I say "your solution is...".  It looks like my comment is addressing your comment, which it is not.  The comment read something along the lines of "what is your evaluation of my edited solution?".  Its deletion may be the source of some confusion.

Comment: Even though we're not in the classroom (well, yeah, you could argue we are), I see the need for pedantry. Thanks for the explanation. -- Generally I tend to answer questions not in a strict "only what the OP asked for" manner, but I try to figure out what the OP *actually meant*. Pointing to the proper use of namespaces and template matching seemed the right thing to do here, including a solution that uses string comparison was even optional for me. Most questions asked here are classic [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) and I've adapted to that.